# cannot bind to DatasourceProperties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am getting the error below when I try configure multiple datasources in Spring boot:

> ```
> Property: xyz.integration.multidatasources.connections.datasource1.username
> Value: safuser
> Origin: class path resource [application.properties]:14:67
> Reason: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseType
> ```

When I try to load multiple datasource configurations. The properties are as below:

```
xyz.integration.multidatasources.connections.datasource1.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/safdb
xyz.integration.multidatasources.connections.datasource1.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
xyz.integration.multidatasources.connections.datasource1.username=auser
xyz.integration.multidatasources.connections.datasource1.password=apassword
```

The  java class is as below:

```
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties;
    import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
    import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;

    @Configuration
    @EnableConfigurationProperties
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "xyz.integration.multidatasources")
    public class MultipleDatasourcesProperties {
        private Map<String, DataSourceProperties> connections = new HashMap<>();

        public Map<String, DataSourceProperties> getConnections() {
            return connections;
        }

        public void setConnections(Map<String, DataSourceProperties> connections) {
            this.connections = connections;
        }
    }
```

Am I missing anything in my configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this ?

**application.properties**

```
primary.url={primary-database-url}      
primary.username={primary-database-username} 
primary.password={primary-database-password} 
primary.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver 
primary.test-on-borrow=true            
primary.validation-query=SELECT 1      


secondary.url={secondary-database-url}
secondary.username={secondary-database-username}
secondary.password={secondary-database-password}
secondary.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
secondary.test-on-borrow=true
secondary.validation-query=SELECT 1
secondary.validation-interval=25200000
```

**Create the configuration beans**

```
@Bean(name = "primaryDataSource")
@ConfigurationProperties("primary")
@Primary
public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}

@Bean(name = "secondaryDataSource")
@ConfigurationProperties("secondary")
public DataSource secondaryDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}
```

Next, create the JdbcTemplate beans that we are going to use for accessing the data sources in our data access layer.

```
@Bean(name = "primaryJdbcTemplate")
    public JdbcTemplate primaryJdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("primary") DataSource primaryDs) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(writeDs);
}
    
@Bean(name = “secondaryJdbcTemplate")
    public JdbcTemplate secondaryJdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("secondary") DataSource secondaryDs) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(secondaryDs);
}
```

**Try accessing properties like this:**

```
@Resource(name = "primaryJdbcTemplate")
private JdbcTemplate primaryJdbcTemplate;

@Resource(name = "secondaryJdbcTemplate")
private JdbcTemplate secondaryJdbcTemplate;


primaryJdbcTemplate.query(“any-query-to-apply-on-primary-data-source”);
```

Comment: Hi Arun. This works if you know in advance the names of the datasources primary, secondary in the code you posted. In my case these datasources are variables ds1, ds2, orderDs, etc. The customer can configure any datasource so I don't think this works. I need to dynamically create and assign these beans.